# pycurl error . TypeError: invalid arguments to setopt

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hice este código con la librería pycurl

```
import io
import pycurl
from StringIO import StringIO    

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(pycurl.URL, "http://www.twitter.com/")
c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ["Accept:"])
c.setopt(pycurl.COOKIEFILE, "cookieDeLogueoTwitter.txt")
c.setopt(pycurl.REFERER,"http://www.twitter.com/")
c.setopt(pycurl.FOLLOWLOCATION, 1)
c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)
c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0)

e = io.BytesIO()
c.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, e.write)

c.perform()
print c.getinfo(pycurl.HTTP_CODE), c.getinfo(pycurl.EFFECTIVE_URL)

content = e.getvalue()

posicion_token = content.find("authenticity_token")

print "El token es"

token = content[posicion_token-48:posicion_token-8]

##
print content[posicion_token-48:posicion_token-8]
##

token = str(token)

print token

c.setopt(pycurl.URL, "https://twitter.com/sessions")
c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ["Accept:"])
c.setopt(pycurl.COOKIEFILE, "cookieDeLogueoTwitter.txt")
c.setopt(pycurl.REFERER,"http://www.twitter.com/")
c.setopt(pycurl.FOLLOWLOCATION, 1)
c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)
c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0)
c.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)

username = "user"
password = "password"

postfields = { "session[username_or_email]" : "usuario" , "session[password]" : "password","return_to_ssl": "true", "scribe_log": "", "redirect_after_login":"%2F", "authenticity_token": token }

print postfields

c.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, postfields)
```

y me tira el siguiente error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\instabot-twitbot\logueo_twitter2.py", line
>   56, in 
>       c.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, postfields) TypeError: invalid arguments to setopt

Pero supuestamente el argumento POSTFIELDS existe según los ejemplos que hay

[Pycurl postfields ejemplo](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/3675/pycurl.POSTFIELDS)

A qué puede deberse el error entonces?

Comment: Pablo, pregunta `postfields` no debiera ser una cadena en vez de un diccionario?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho así parece, publicalo como respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que ocurre es que estás enviando directamente un diccionario en `postfields` cuando debieras pasar una cadena. Lo que eventualmente podrías hacer es:

```
import urllib

postfields = urllib.urlencode(postfields)
c.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, postfields)
print postfields

> return_to_ssl=true&session%5Bpassword%5D=password&authenticity_token=111&redirect_after_login=%252F&scribe_log=&session%5Busername_or_email%5D=usuario
```

Mediante [`urllib.encode()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) podemos mapear una secuencia de tuplas (en tu caso el diccionario `postfields`) a una cadena valida para un request POST.